# How to involve array into a function definition in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I try to define a function to calculate the distance between two atoms. I defined a 2D array in the main function to store the coordinates of m atoms, e.g. nn[m][3], m is the index of the atom and the 3 represent to x<-1,y<-2,z<-3.

But when I define the function--> float dist() {   }, my Dev C++ compiler said that
'nn' undeclared (first use this function) (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

the following is my code to define the function dist(), the error occurs in the line x1=nn[a][0]
thank you and best

```
float dist(int a, int b){  // a,b are parameters of function dist(), a is one order of 
//a atom, b is another, e.g. nn[a][x,y,z], and nn[b][x,y,z]
float d;
float f1(float);// f1 is a fn to calculate the square of a number
float x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z3;
x1=nn[a][0];
x2=nn[b][0];
y1=nn[a][1];
y2=nn[b][1];
z1=nn[a][2];
z2=nn[b][2];
float nn[a][0],nn[a][1],nn[a][2],nn[b][0],nn[b][1],nn[b][2];
d=sqrt(f1(x1-x2)+f1(y1-y2)+f1(z1-z2));
return d;
}
```

there is what I have right now:

```
// build an array for 4 Molecules, with initial radius between 2 nearest molecules
// number of 2 nearest number is n-1
// number of not nearest neighbor
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
float f1(float p){ //calculat the square
    float k;
    k=p*p;
    return k;
    }
float dist(int a, int b){  // a,b are parameters of function dist(), a is one order of 
//a atom, b is another, e.g. nn[a][x,y,z], and nn[b][x,y,z]
float d;
float f1(float);// f1 is a fn to calculate the square of a number
float x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z3;
x1=nn[a][0];
x2=nn[b][0];
y1=nn[a][1];
y2=nn[b][1];
z1=nn[a][2];
z2=nn[b][2];
float nn[a][0],nn[a][1],nn[a][2],nn[b][0],nn[b][1],nn[b][2];
d=sqrt(f1(x1-x2)+f1(y1-y2)+f1(z1-z2));
return d;
}

int main (void) 
{
    int n=4;// # of molecules 
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;rj,rk;//i,j,k are dummy variables, rj, rk are the the size of array rn[],rd[]
    rj=(n-1)-1;//the # of nearest neighbor of 4 molecules, rj=(n-1)-1,-1 for c starts at 0
    rk=n*(n-1)/2-(n-1)-1;//the # of non-nearest neighbor of 4 molecules, for n molecules, it will be 


float rn[rj],rd[rk];// nn is the number array of the atoms
// nn[][] is the coordinates of the atom, n[][0]<-x,n[][1]<-y,n[][2]<-z,
// rn[] is the distance between nearest neighbor
// rk[] is the distance between non-nearest neighbors
/* give intiate coordinate */
int nn[4][3]={{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0},{3,0,0}};

  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
            {printf("\n");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)

        printf("nn[%d][%d] is %d   ",j,i,nn[j][i]);
 }
printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

float d,dd;
printf("%d,  \n%d  \n",nn[1][0],nn[2][0]);
d=sqrt(f1(nn[1][0]-nn[2][0])+f1(nn[1][1]-nn[2][1])+f1(nn[1][2]-nn[2][2])); //calculate the distance   
dd=dist(1,2); // test the function
printf("%f\n%f\n",d,dd);

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is too messed up to be answered properly. In general, if you've declared the array `nn` in function `main`, then you should pass it to function `dist` when you call it. But the again, I see this array being declared at the bottom of this function as well, so what exactly were you planning there? Also, what is that function definition `float f1(float)` doing inside function `dist`? Some basic coding rules are obviously missing here.

Comment: Hi Barak, I defined the array "nn[m][3]" in the "main()" function, I do not  know how to pass the array to function "dist". I think this is my problem. The function float f1(float) will calculate the square of a number. eg. f1(3)=9. I am a new programmer who is willing to learn, please give me some advice

Comment: Adding your entire code might help...

Comment: added what I have now, thank you

Comment: Look at this question I asked, I want to give myself 4 years back, for whom is in the some shoes as mine, some suggestion: 1) although you code in c

Answer (score 1):

change

```
float dist(int a, int b){
```

to

```
float dist(int a, int b, int nn[4][3]){
```

change

```
dd=dist(1,2);
```

to

```
dd=dist(1,2, nn);
```

change

```
int i=0,j=0,k=0;rj,rk;
```

to

```
int i=0,j=0,k=0,rj,rk;
```

change

```
float nn[a][0],nn[a][1],nn[a][2],nn[b][0],nn[b][1],nn[b][2];
```

to

```
//float nn[a][0],nn[a][1],nn[a][2],nn[b][0],nn[b][1],nn[b][2];
```

change

```
float x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z3;
```

to

```
float x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2;
```

Comment: Thank you Bluepixy,it works! One thing I do not understand is the line y'float dist(int a,int b, int nn[4][3])' why do you use int type for the array nn[4][3] but not float type?

Comment: Hi, bluepixy, I get it now the nn[][] I defined in dist() and main() must be consistent, I think that is why. Thank you again and best wishes

Comment: actually it is a silly question. if we want to use double type data we need to use %lf <- long float